# React native state is rendering array of objects before the objects are set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

My name is omar jandali. I have a react native project I am working on.

I have two files setup which are `PropertiesContext` and `PropertiesScreen`

In the `PropertiesContext` file. I have a function called getPropertyDetails. This function is called after an axios request is made to an api and grabs a list of 40 properties info from zillow api.

In the `setPropertieyDetails` function. `I map through the list of api results`. For each property. I want to make another api request to a different api in order to get the property tax rate for that property followed by calculating and setting a bunch of different information about the proeprty to the property object. For each property, I then want to push each property ojbect with the calculations to the `results` state. Once the result state is set with all the properties calculated, then render the entire list at 1 time.

What is happening is that for each properties that is being mapped, it is sending the request of all 40 properties and then loading `results`. It is then loading search property 1 at a time as the `axios` request is returning the results of that request and doing the calculations.

I dont want it to render 1 at a time. I want it to render only after all the requests are sent and all the request have responses and objects stored in results.

Is there a way to delay the rendering until all of the `axios` request come back and the entire array is set rather than rendering an empty array and then rendering each property 1 at a time in the View?

the list is rendered when `loading === true`

`PropertiesContext.js`

```
 ...

 const [results, setResults] = useState([])

 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

 ...

 const getProperties = () => {
     setLoading(true)
     ...
     axios.request(properties)
     .then(function (response) {
         ...
         grabMoreDetails(response.data)
     }).catch(function (error) {
             error[0] === 'AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500'
                 ? setErrorMessage('There was an issue retreiving properties')
                 : null
     });
 }

 const grabMoreDetails = (generalResponse) => {
     axios.post('https://api.precisely.com/oauth/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials', {
         headers: {
             'Authorization': ...,
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
     })
     .then((response) => {
         setPropertyDetails(response.data.access_token, generalResponse)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log('token error: ', error)
     })
 }

 const setPropertyDetails = (token, generalResponse) => {
     let skippedProps = 0
     generalResponse.results.map((property, index) => {
         if(index + skippedProps <= generalResponse.results.length - 1){
             let taxRate
             let propertyAddress = property.streetAddress + ", " +
                                                         property.city + ', ' +
                                                         property.state + ' ' + property.zipcode
             axios.get('https://api.precisely.com/property/v2/attributes/byaddress', {
                 params: {
                     address: propertyAddress,
                     attributes: 'taxAmount, assessedValue'
                 },
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                 }
             })
             .then((response) => {
                 taxRate = ((parseInt(response.data.propertyAttributes.taxAmount) / parseInt(response.data.propertyAttributes.assessedValue)) * 100).toFixed(2)
                 let downPaymentAmount = calculateDownPaymentAmount(property.price, 20)
                 let downPaymentPercent = calculateDownPaymentPercent(property.price, downPaymentAmount)
                 let loanAmount = calculateLoanAmount(property.price, downPaymentAmount)
                 let mortgageAmount = calculateMortgageAmount(loanAmount, 30, 6.485)
                 let monthlyTaxAmount = Math.round((calculatePropertyTaxAnnual(taxRate, property.price)) / 12)
                 let homeInsurance = calculateHomeInsuranceAmount(property.price)
                 let monthlyRevenue = property.rentZestimate
                 let expenses = 0
                 let hoaFee = property.hoaFee
                 hoaFee === null 
                     ? expenses = mortgageAmount + hoaFee + monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance 
                     : expenses = mortgageAmount + monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance
                 let monthlyExpenses = 0
                 let monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage = 0
                 hoaFee === null
                     ? monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage = hoaFee + monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance
                     : monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage = monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance
                 hoaFee === null
                     ? monthlyExpenses = mortgageAmount + hoaFee + monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance
                     : monthlyExpenses = mortgageAmount + monthlyTaxAmount + homeInsurance
                 let netOperatingIncome = Math.round(monthlyRevenue - monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage)
                 let yearlyNetOperatingIncome = netOperatingIncome * 12
                 let monthlyCashFLow = Math.round(netOperatingIncome - mortgageAmount)
                 let yearlyCashFlow = monthlyCashFLow * 12
                 let currentCapRate = ((yearlyNetOperatingIncome / property.price) * 100).toFixed(2)
                 let currentCashOnCashReturn = ((yearlyCashFlow / downPaymentAmount) * 100).toFixed(2)
                 let year1ReturnOnInvestment = ((yearlyNetOperatingIncome / downPaymentAmount) * 100).toFixed(2)
 
                 property.investment = {
                     downPaymentAmount: downPaymentAmount,
                     downPaymentPercent: downPaymentPercent,
                     loanAmount: loanAmount,
                     mortgageAmount: mortgageAmount,
                     monthlyTaxAmount: monthlyTaxAmount,
                     homeInsurance: homeInsurance,
                     monthlyRevenue: monthlyRevenue,
                     expenses: expenses,
                     netOperatingIncome: netOperatingIncome,
                     yearlyNetOperatingIncome: yearlyNetOperatingIncome,
                     monthlyCashFLow: monthlyCashFLow,
                     yearlyCashFlow: yearlyCashFlow,
                     currentCapRate: currentCapRate,
                     currentCashOnCashReturn: currentCashOnCashReturn,
                     year1ReturnOnInvestment: year1ReturnOnInvestment,
                     monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage: monthlyExpensesWithoutMortgage,
                 }
                 setResults(results => [...results, property])
             })
             .catch((error) => {
                 skippedProps++
             })
         }
     })
     setLoading(false)
 }

 return(
     ...
 )

}
```

Comment: Check `Promise.all`

Comment: @Konrad Th thing is that for each iteration of the ```generalResponse.results``` objects... I have to send a unique request. I dont htink that works with promise all

Comment: You haven't shown how the functions are called, which is the key here, I think. I understand there are 2 problems: 1. not sending all 40 on every render, which is probably solved by using a [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects), and 2. send a 2nd request only if all 1st responses have received, there you need a list of the requests to wait for, and on each response check if all items of that list have responded as well. [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can help here.